# Powershell to change password not working

Tags: powershell, change-password

I have a long Powershell script that "builds" a PC for me, by adding everything I need to a Windows 7 (32 bit) PC.  I have had this script for several years and it has worked fine.  One of the first things I do is change the password.  This line of code suddenly doesn't work in the script -

```
([adsi]"WinNT://ccm2756/Administrator").SetPassword("NewPassword")
```

I get "the following exception has occurred while retrieving member SetPassword. Network path not found."

Has worked just fine all this time.  And on the same PCs.  Haven't changed the script, haven't changed the PCs (I've burned the images back to saved based operating systems).  Suddenly, I am getting this error?  And yet, if I open a command line and type "Powershell" to get to a PS Command line and run that exact same command, it goes through without any errors.

What am I missing here?

Comment: does that system name exist at the time the line is called?

Comment: for me, on win7ps5.1, there is NO `.SetPassword()` method on that object. i have no idea why, tho. [*blush*]

Comment: It's just very strange, because the image I build on is from about 3 years ago and I have used this script several times over the past couple years without it giving me that error on the same image.

Comment: i just noticed you mentioned 32bit win7 ... my test was on 64bit win7 & ps5.1 so that may make a difference. have you confirmed that you are still running on 32bit win7 when you test this?